# Facebox popup messaging system asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebox, private-messaging

I'm building a website where users can either contact each other via a private messaging system through the web application. Instead of being sent to a different webpage, I wanted to make it so if you click send message, a popup (exactly like what sending a new message on facebook looks like) comes up and you can send your message without being redirected to a new page. After you click send, the popup goes away.

I've written the NewMessage.aspx page but I'm pretty confused on how to implement the popup (facebox?) feature. A lot of posts I find on facebox are mostly about how the asp.net button postback doesn't work so I'm wondering if facebox is the best way to go about implementing this feature? And if so, can anyone maybe explain the basics of how to implement facebox? Is it something that comes with ASP.net or is it something I need to download to use? I'm not really familiar with jQuery or Ajax so if these are things I need in order to implement this, maybe some tips on how to use those with asp.net webforms would be helpful too.

Thanks